# Short Story collection about monsters

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, childrens-novel, illustrated-story

I've been searching for a collection of short stories I read as a kid. I can't say how old I was, but old enough to read because I read them myself, and certainly I read them over seven years ago (I am 18 now). It was a large book, physically, and thick. It contained short stories (I can't say how many or even if they were all by the same author) and loads of illustrations. In fact, the stories were printed on top of full page or even double spread illustrations. More than that, however, and details get shaky. I'm almost positive one was about making soup; there was one short story that was about a race, and the illustration was of a monster wearing a runners vest, shorts and trousers, and he had yellow or orange skin. There was another story I am almost 100% positive was called "Two heads are better than one". Every story was about monsters and I don't think humans were even involved in any way. Anyone got any ideas? I've filed this under Horror because, y'know, monsters, but I can't even be sure the stories were meant to be scary.

Comment: Since you know the title of one of the stories, look it up on [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/). There are 3 short stories with this title, hopefully you can determine which one is the one you've read and which collection you read it in.

Comment: @Gilles I'm guessing I'm missing something but it comes up with 0 results

Comment: Make sure to change “Name” to “Fiction Titles” in the dropdown.

Comment: Embarassing....

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem any of them match the story. I was sure that was the title, now I'm doubting myself. I realise my question must be the longest shot ever, so thank you, you got further than I managed.

Comment: Could it be a [Ruth Manning-Sanders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth_Manning-Sanders) collection? I'm thinking "A Book of Monsters" but there may be other candidates.

Comment: @Fruitbat, A good suggestion, I got excited for a moment. RM-S seems to collect folk tales and such into books and I'm sure that the one I'm looking for is original. At least the stories seem too "small" (such as a monster running a race) to be a folk tale. In the spreads I found online there are humans in her stories, inc. A Book of Monsters, and there weren't (almost sure) in the collection; the art style is off as well. Perhaps the right word for the art style used in the book I'm looking for is "surreal". But I know how impossible my question is so thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it!

The specifically named "Monster Stories", 2002, compiled by Andy Charman. Did indeed involve cooking, and a marathon, and has a story called *Two heads are worse than one* (I was close!)

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess, is it possible that one of those stories would be Forrest J Ackerman's *The Mute Question* which ends with a punchline of:

> "Two heads are better than none"?

Comment: What, no spoiler protection?

Comment: @user14111: Better?